# can I disable Tor to view Youtube videos?

Tags: support

I want to watch all YouTube videos at my discretion. Can I temporarily disable Tor to view YouTube videos?

Answer (score 2):

You have different ways to watch YouTube videos:

1. Use some browser or browser profile which does not use Tor. This way you'll loose your anonymity.
2. Use the HTML5 player. Visit the [HTML5 page at YouTube](https://youtube.com/html5) and request to use the HTML5 player. When it is active you can watch many YouTube videos through Tor and without Flash.
3. Download the video and watch it with an installed software. There are several programs which download the video to your harddrive (through Tor). You can than use a locally installed player and watch the video.

Comment: That is a good idea! I appreciate your help. :)